# SSh client/Server is in-built in Windows server 2016 or it is installed externally?

Tags: openssh

I have windows server 2016 installed on a VM.
Is it true that Windows server 2016 comes with preinstalled SSH client/server because when i searched online,I found various links and tutorials wherein  i am supposed to install SSH client/server externally like :-

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

So can't understand if Windows server 2016 comes with preinstalled SSH client/sever or not.Plz help